# React: Adding object to an array

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Im very new on REACT but giving me some challenges away from the youtube tutorials I'm trying to create a mini-app where you can introduce the name of a friend in order to fill an array. It's working really good with my code so far.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      friends: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({
      friends: this.state.friends.concat(this.state.value)
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {

    let friendsList = this.state.friends;
    const Friends = friendsList.map((friend, index) => 
      <li key={index}>
        <span>{friend}</span>
      </li>
    )

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="header">

          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter the name of your friend"/>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>

          <div className="content">
            <ul> {Friends} </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**The Question:**

Now I dont need to add just a string like any name, I need to add an object with atributes like name, age and birthday. BUT, React is telling me:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {name})

when I'm trying doing this:

```
this.setState({
  friends: this.state.friends.concat({"name": "xxx"})
});
```

I've check another similar question without any luck, even tutorials it seems that are not going for this point. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the `setState` - React just can't render `objects`. You must change how you render a `Friend`, for example like this:

```
const Friends = friendsList.map((friend, index) => 
  <li key={index}>
    <span>{friend.name} - {friend.age}</span>
  </li>
)
```

It should work then - remember that React can only render strings, numbers and other components by default. For other data types you must provide a render function.

Comment: Thank you, it's working but I'm geeting: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, age}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object)

Comment: There must be another issue assuming you only render `name` and `age`. You must still render `{friend}` somewhere. Please search for that through your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it resolves your problem.

```
const Friends = friendsList.map((friend, index) => 
  <li key={index}>
    <span>{friend.name}</span>
  </li>
)
```

Also, you don't need to wrap the text inside a span.

```
const Friends = friendsList.map((friend, index) => 
  <li key={index}>{friend.name}</li>
)
```

Comment: it helps a lot! please see my coment on @Przemysław Zalewski answer